# How to I store multiple inputs from keyboard into a variable in java?

Tags: java, variables, input, while-loop, substring

(I can't use arrays or anything more advanced like that. I can use substring and loops, that's pretty much it.) I have a program which constantly asks the user to enter name. How can i have them enter different names again and again and then print out all of those different names out separated by a comma. how do I store multiple inputs into one variable? when user enters hi, all names they've typed in should out print separated by a comma and the loop should quit. I can get the lop to quit but not all of the names they've entered to print out.

```
public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Names;
        String x = "hi";

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Please enter a name: ");
            Names=s.nextLine();
            int len = Names.length(); 

            if (Names.compareTo(x) == 0) {
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use arrays or collections? They're made for this.

Comment: use string itself and separate two name using some delimiter which must not be used when writing name

Comment: and when you want to print the name replace the delimiter with the ','

Comment: Do string concatenations and at the end print the result.

Comment: Everything you post here is licensed under [**CC BY-SA 3.0 (Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service)**](https://stackexchange.com/legal) you cannot delete the question after publishing it. We understand that having it up will cause you trouble at work or school. If so you may want to read [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA 3.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0). **Do not edit the question to make it look like a low quality post.**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StringBuilder` to accumulate them:

```
final String QUIT_FLAG = "hi";
String currName = null;
StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a name: ");
    currName = sc.nextLine();
    if (QUIT_FLAG.equals(currName)) {
        break;
    }

    if (names.length() > 0) {
        names.append(',');
    }
    names.append(currName);
}

System.out.println(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used

```
Names = s.nextLine();
```

in your `while` loop. This `=` operator clears the `Names` variable and assigns then last value given. So in order preserve previous values use `+=` operator.

So try using,

```
Names += ", " + s.nextLine();
```

And I suggest you use `equals()` instead of `compareTo()`. Change your `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Names = null;

    while (true) {

        System.out.print("Please enter a name: ");
        String name = s.nextLine();

        if (name.toLowerCase().equals("hi")) {
            break;
        }

        if (Names == null) {
            Names = name;
        } else {
            Names += ", " + name;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Names : " + Names);
}
```